# Is it possible to display specific property from JSON only?

Tags: json, angular, tree

I am looking at this page:
https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples
 with Angular tree examples and want to use one with checkboxes. Issue I have is that JSON I have to populate the tree is in given format:

```
const TREE_DATA = {
   "tableOfContents":[
      {
         "id":"{039CCB54-97EB-4C64-80E0-B3D44482172B}",
         "caption":"Overview",
         "file":"hlpIntroduction",
         "iconIndex":-1,
         "children":[

         ]
      },      
      {
         "id":"{9204FD14-7841-40B9-A0DA-8B80E9EB0152}",
         "caption":"Account Settings",
         "file":null,
         "iconIndex":-1,
         "children":[
            {
               "id":"{BFB2F082-981A-4E0B-A122-5320B868B57B}",
               "caption":"My Account",
               "file":"hlpCMStartPage",
               "iconIndex":-1,
               "children":[

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
  ]
};
```

This is showing all the properties. With this sample I would like it to show  'Overview' and 'Account Settings' as first level nodes (under tableOfContents), and 'My Account' as second level node - child to 'Account Settings'. So only the 'caption' value would be displayed in the tree.

I was looking into buildFileTree method but could not figure out how to change it to achieve what I need here.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: i think the structure of your json is pretty good to implement what you are looking for . can you describe more the clear way what you want ?

Comment: I simply want tree to be showing only captions. All other properties should not be visible..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
this.displayData = this.TREE_DATA.tableOfContents.map(item => ({
  caption: item.caption,
  children: item.children.map(y => ({ caption:y.caption}))
}));
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-opg8di?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: yes this is what you are looking for .. accept this.

Comment: Thanks that is the solution